# Delink a button from <li> element

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I have a button inside an "li" element. There is a request performed on clicking on the "li" element and another request is performed on clicking on that button.

```
    <li style="cursor: pointer; padding-bottom: 2px;" class="list-group-item"  ng-class="{'active': $index === selectedIndex}" ng-click="showQuery(segname.id, $index, segname)" ng-repeat="segname in segmentsCreatedName">
     <span style="padding: 10px 15px; display: inline-block;">{{segname.name}}</span>
     <a class="btn btn-default pull-right" href="/apps/{{currApp}}/messages/automate/segments/{{segname.id}}/write">AutoMessage</a>
    </li>
```

I want to delink the button from `<li>` so that only one request is made on clicking the button. Is there any way I can do it?

Comment: It would be nice if you can post your code and structure your question properly

Comment: `e.stopPropagation();` would keep the event from bubbling past the clicked element.  As guru says, we need to see your javascript.  It also helps to build a Fiddle at jsfiddle.net.

Answer (score 0):

You got one of two options.

First option is you stop the click at the link.

Second option is you check to see what was clicked on before you call your function.

Basic idea

**HTML:**

```
<div id="x">xxx<a href="#">aaa</a></div>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
document.getElementById("x").onclick = function (e) {  //better to use addEventListener
   e = e || window.event;
   var target = e.srcElement || e.target;
    if (target.tagName.toLowerCase()!=="a") {
         alert("not the link");   
    }
};
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rLat4/)

Answer (score -2):

In short, the way you're describing can't be done.

As long as you want a request performed by clicking the `<li>` element as well you can't both have it linked and delinked to and action at the same time. Because the button is contained within the `<li>` element any click of it also triggers a click on the element.

What are you actually trying to achieve by having a button and a clickable `<li>` it's nested in? Perhaps if you added a bit more info about what you're trying to achieve a better work-around could be suggested.

Comment: I know his question is a bit odd, but I don't think it can't be done. EDIT: don't know why someone downvoted you though